# Django - how do I make the id go to the next avalaible number? (adding records outside of app)

Tags: django

I have to add 200 records into a table as i'm migrating data from an old SQLite database. I'm doing this through external software and everything is fine, it's just a simple copy and paste, aside from one issue.

If I want to add a new record through the Django app - it gives me an error that the ID has been already used. Every time I hit enter to add a record it cycles through to next id. To be able to add a new record successfully, I would need to cycle through 200 errors to arrive at the next available ID.

Is there anyway I speed this process up by allowing Django to count the new records that weren't added in the app and take them into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of the table is not up to date. Depending on your database you should run an sql query like;

`ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 201;`

201 is the latest id + 1